# Custom hash: is object in a dictionary?

Tags: python, hash

I'd like to check if my object is already present in a dictionary based on it's `name`. My current implementation does not return expected results, so for sure I am missing something here.

My class:

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
    name: str
    number: int
        
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)
```

and the code:

```
d = {}
foo1 = Foo('foo1', 1)
foo2 = Foo('foo2', 2)
foo3 = Foo('foo1', 3)
foo4 = Foo('foo4', 1)
d[foo1] = foo1
d[foo2] = foo2

print(f'Is foo3 in d? {foo3 in d}') # prints: "Is foo3 in d? False" Expected True (NOK)
print(f'Is foo4 in d? {foo4 in d}') # prints: "Is foo4 in d? False" Expected False (OK)
print(f'foo1 hash: {foo1.__hash__()}') # 4971911885166104854
print(f'foo3 hash: {foo1.__hash__()}') # 4971911885166104854
```

Do I need anything else than the `__hash__()` implementation?

Comment: first off it doesn't look like You actually added the foo3 to the dictionary and here You use foo1: `print(f'foo3 hash: {foo1.__hash__()}')`

Comment: @Matiiss It doesn't matter if this specific object is in, I am interested if that `id` is in (`foo3` had id `foo1`). For my purpose it means that the object is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the equality dunder also. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) of `__hash__` and `__eq__`:

> If a class does not define an **eq**() method it should not define a **hash**() operation either;

After I add the `__eq__`, I get the following behavior.

```
    def __eq__(self, x):
        return hash(self) == hash(x)
```

On running the program, I get:

```
Is foo3 in d? True
Is foo4 in d? False
foo1 hash: -4460692046661292337
foo3 hash: -4460692046661292337
```